# Fluid Measurements when using z-index

Tags: html, css, responsive, z-index

I based my current attempts off of this thread
https://intellipaat.com/community/22509/how-to-overlay-one-div-over-another-div

But my problem is that while I can get both layers to be exactly the same width and height when I use fixed measurements like in the other thread, I'm not able to get the height of the top layer to meet the height of the bottom layer when I switch width to 95% of the wrapper div.

Here's my code for the fixed measurements:

```
.banner {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .backplane, .frontplane {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .backplane {
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
    .frontplane {
        border: 10px solid blue;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-opacity: 0;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

here's the CSS for fluid measurements of a 95% width wrapper.  if I add height of 100% to the .backplane, .frontplane {} class, the view of the frontplane gets messed up.

```
.banner {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 95%; 
        position: relative;
    }
    .backplane, .frontplane {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .backplane {
        border: 10px solid black;
    }
    .frontplane {
        border: 10px solid blue;
        border-radius: 50px;
        background-opacity: 0;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

here's my HTML

```
    <div class="banner">
    <div class="backplane" id="back">
        <img src="background.jpg" width="100%" alt=" ">
    </div>

    <div class="frontplane" id="front">
        <img src="mars.jpg" width="30%" margin="0 auto" alt="Mars Logo">
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought to perhaps use JavaScript to get the height of the fluid backplane and assign it to the frontplane like thus:

```
document.getElementById("front").height() = document.getElementById("back").height();
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's a screenshot of the first example with fixed measurements

[image: Fixed Measurements]

And here's a screenshot of the second example with fluid measurements.  the width is correct for both layers but not the height.  the blue border shows where the height is.  it needs to match the black border.

[image: Fluid Measurements]

Would someone be able to suggest a way to get the guild height to work properly?  That would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the dimensions of an element relatively (x%). The parent (.banner) is used for this. Since you are setting `position: absolute;` on front and back, there is no more content which prevents the parent from collapsing. Basically you are reading the height of an empty div.

By leaving the back with default position, `.banner` has content which prevents it from collapsing.

```css
.banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
}

/* .backplane, */
.frontplane {
  /* width: 100%; */
  position: absolute;
}

.backplane {
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.frontplane {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  /* background-opacity: 0; /* this does not exist use: background-color: transparent; */
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  /* tie to perimeter */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="backplane" id="back">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/DDD/EEE&text=back" width="100%" alt=" ">
  </div>

  <div class="frontplane" id="front">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/CCC/777&text=front" width="30%" margin="0 auto" alt="Mars Logo">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```